# Searchable multi-level dropdown in Semantic

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to make a dropdown with submenus and a search box. So far the search string only applies to the first level menu and does not look into second level menu items. Is there a way to perform the search beyond the first level?
Minimal example here:

HTML:

```
<div class="ui segment">

<div class="ui search selection dropdown" id="test">
  <span class="text">Search Selection</span>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="text">Category 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <span class="text">Category 2</span>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">Item 2A</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2B</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <span class="text">Category 3</span>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">Item 3A</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3B</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#test')
  .dropdown();
```

CSS:

```
.ui.selection.dropdown .menu {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/o1aLysve/